# Listing network hardware - why does Ubuntu sometimes hide eth0 until it is connected?

Tags: networking

On my laptop, I have Ubuntu 14.04. This laptop has both an RJ45 connector for wired Ethernet, and wireless/WiFi. I have noticed, however, that on this laptop, right after reboot, I have only this:

```
$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:608 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:608 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:76086 (76.0 KB)  TX bytes:76086 (76.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:71:XX:XX:b1:XX  
          inet addr:YY.0.XX.XX  Bcast:YY.0.XX.XX  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::XXXX:XXXX:fe3f:b1db/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2589 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2044 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1458453 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:292837 (292.8 KB)
```

In fact, if I turn off wireless / uncheck "Enable Wi-Fi" from the Network Manager applet, I have only this:

```
$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:178068 (178.0 KB)  TX bytes:178068 (178.0 KB)
```

As you can see from the above `ifconfig` dumps, `eth0` corresponding to the wired ethernet network is not listed at all! And in fact, it won't appear, until I connect the laptop with a router/switch, and the laptop gets an IP address!? In fact, while there is nothing connected to the RJ45 connector, the laptop reports just this via `lshw`:

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: XX:71:XX:XX:b1:XX
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.2.0-42-generic firmware=N/A ip=YY.0.XX.XX latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:f7c00000-f7c7ffff memory:f7c80000-f7c8ffff
```

Notice, the wired/`eth0` adapter is not listed anywhere ?!

Otherwise, when I've connected the laptop's RJ45 connector with a network cable to a router or Internet cable, I get an `ifconfig` entry like:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:2b:XX:XX:XX
          inet6 addr: fe80::YYYY:YYYY:fe0a:YYYY/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1980 (1.9 KB)  TX bytes:12108 (12.1 KB)
```

In fact, in the above snippet, the `eth0` didn't even get an IP4 address assigned; so apparently all it matters is that it is connected somehow to an Ethernet network.

Note, on this laptop, `/etc/network/interfaces` was containing just:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

... however, I added `auto eth0` as a last line, saved and rebooted - and there was no change in behavior whatsoever (i.e. `eth0` was still hidden, until connected).

Now, on the other hand, I manage a desktop machine as an Ubuntu server (also 14.04), and on it I've always seen `eth0` show up in `ifconfig` - even if I have pulled the network cable from the desktop's RJ45 connector?!

So my questions are:

- Why does Ubuntu sometimes "hide" `eth0` (or other network interfaces) until they are connected - and why is it not consistent (i.e. on desktop it is always shown, on laptop it is not shown until connected)?
- How can I list all network hardware, on an Ubuntu that "hides" network interfaces like this - as in that case, as shown above, not even `sudo lshw` works?

Answer (score 3):

`ifconfig` by default shows only the interfaces that are Up. To see all interfaces, including the down one(s):

```
ifconfig -a
```

Note that, in GNU/Linux `ifconfig` (comes with `net-tools`) is deprecated in favor of newer `ip` (comes with `iptoute2`). With `ip` you can do:

```
ip addr show
```

Shorthand:

```
ip a
```

Check `man ip` to get more idea.

Comment: Thanks @heemayl - but that doesn't help me here; I'm on my laptop now, working on Internet through `wlan0`, and both `ifconfig -a` and `ip addr show` show only `lo` and `wlan0`, no sign of `eth0`.

Comment: Just to add for those reading, in case my previous comment was too indeterminate - `ifconfig -a` and `ip addr show` do NOT work for me, since they still do not show `eth0` when it is not connected to network.